# Why are the fractions of my table entries divided by four in my contingency table?

Tags: r, count, margins, contingency

this is my contingency table `cxTable`:

```
                Always Wrong Almst Always Wrg Sometimes Wrong Not Wrong At All
  Lower Class           1344              166             146               73
  Working Class        11997             1775            1105              355
  Middle Class         11221             2320            1188              341
  Upper Class            696              177             125               47
```

Adding the margins works well:

```
> marginCxTable = addmargins(cxTable)
> marginCxTable

                Always Wrong Almst Always Wrg Sometimes Wrong Not Wrong At All   Sum
  Lower Class           1344              166             146               73  1729
  Working Class        11997             1775            1105              355 15232
  Middle Class         11221             2320            1188              341 15070
  Upper Class            696              177             125               47  1045
  Sum                  25258             4438            2564              816 33076
```

However adding the fractions my sum is only 25% instead of 100%. All other entries are also divided by four.

```
> prop.table(marginCxTable)

                Always Wrong Almst Always Wrg Sometimes Wrong Not Wrong At All          Sum
  Lower Class   0.0101584230     0.0012546862    0.0011035192     0.0005517596 0.0130683880
  Working Class 0.0906775305     0.0134160721    0.0083519773     0.0026832144 0.1151287943
  Middle Class  0.0848122506     0.0175353731    0.0089793204     0.0025773975 0.1139043415
  Upper Class   0.0052606119     0.0013378280    0.0009447938     0.0003552425 0.0078984762
  Sum           0.1909088161     0.0335439594    0.0193796106     0.0061676140 0.2500000000
```

I'm probably missing something very simple. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to do `prop.table()` first, before `addmargins()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @joran's comment, you want to do `prop.table()` before `addmargins()`. Using the `mtcars` data to illustrate so that others can reproduce the output:

```
mt <- table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$am)
addmargins(prop.table(mt))
#           0       1     Sum
# 4   0.09375 0.25000 0.34375
# 6   0.12500 0.09375 0.21875
# 8   0.37500 0.06250 0.43750
# Sum 0.59375 0.40625 1.00000
```

Comment: thanks to you and @joran. works great. still out of curiosity, why are all my entries divided by four?

Comment: @AmirRahbaran They are not being divided by four. Rather, they are being divided by the entire total of the table. Sum up the entries of `marginCxTable` (total = 132,304). Divide each entry by 132,304 and you will get the unexpected output. This is what `prop.table` does to any existing table.

Comment: OMG, this helped me a lot. Thank you so much.